# C - Unexpected results with fork and sleep functions

Tags: c, fork, sleep

I found this [Redirect ouput to another instance terminal window](https://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/114976-redirect-ouput-another-instance-terminal-window.html) post and tried to play with similar code alternatives, but got unexpected results when using the sleep function, or similar, in conjunction with the fork function.

I run the code below from a ("parent") terminal window. The program is supposed to open another (child) terminal window and print some text to both the parent and child terminals in an infinite loop.

The issue is that the frequency of the printing in each window is not the same, in fact it can be very different.

I tried 4 alternative loops (one need to comment out only 1 of the 4 alternatives at the same time). The alternative-1 is too fast to see much and the printing frequencies *look* similar in both windows.

The issues arise when I try to slow down the loop, either with the sleep function or a long secondary loop (*), in the alternatives-2, -3 and -4. There, one can see that the timing of text outputs becomes out of sync between the 2 terminals and, while the messages (seem to) print with the desired periodicity in the parent window, e.g. with 1 second delay with sleep(1), the periodicity in the child window seems random and lagging (eg on my machine it takes ~200 seconds before the first output in the child window). Alternative-4  is similar to alternative-2, but with fwrite instead of fprintf.

My questions : why such a lag between the two windows? Is this lag "deterministic" or random? What would be the way to make both terminals print at the same, regular, frequency?

I'm on Linux. `gcc logwindow.c -o logwindow` should be enough to compile the code.

(*) I am aware that using a long loop (in alternative-3) instead of the sleep function is bad practice. I just tried to see if it would  give different results from the sleep function.

```
#include <stdlib.h>                 // system
#include <stdio.h>                  // tempnam, sprintf
#include <unistd.h>                 // sleep
#include <sys/types.h>          // pid_t

FILE *logwindow(){
  char *fp = tmpnam(NULL); //generate a random filepath/name
  char cmd[256];
  pid_t pid;

  mkfifo(fp, 0777);
  pid = fork();

  if (pid==0) {
      sprintf(cmd, "xterm -e \"cat %s\"", fp);
      system(cmd);
      return(NULL);
    }
  return fopen(fp, "w");
}


int main(){
    FILE *log = logwindow();

    if (log == NULL) {
        printf("child process, exiting\n"); 
        exit(0);
    }

    else {
        printf("parent process, keep going\n"); 
        int i=0;


        /* comment out only 1 alternative out of the 4 */

        // alternative-1 

        for(;;){
            fprintf(log, "i=%d, Child Terminal here\n", i); // print to child terminal
            printf("i=%d,  Parent Terminal here\n", i);     // print to parent terminal
            i++;
        }


        // alternative-2
        /*
        for(;;){
            fprintf(log, "i=%d, Child Terminal here\n", i); // print to child terminal
            printf("i=%d,  Parent Terminal here\n", i);     // print to parent terminal
            sleep(1);
            i++;
        }
        */

        // alternative-3
        /*
        int j=0;
        for(i=0;i<100000;i++){
            fprintf(log, "i=%d, Child Terminal here\n", i); // print to child terminal
            printf("i=%d,  Parent Terminal here\n", i);     // print to parent terminal
            for(j=0;j<5000000;j++){}                        // simulate the sleep function
        }
        */      

        // alternative-4
        /*
        char alt4text[] = "Child Terminal here\n";          
        for(;;){
            fwrite(alt4text, 1, sizeof(alt4text),log);          // print to child terminal
            printf("i=%d,  Parent Terminal here\n", i);     // print to parent terminal
            sleep(1);
            i++;
        }
        */


    }
}
```

Comment: Try calling `fflush(log)` after your prints... what happens then?

Comment: It worked. Thank you.

Comment: for(j=0;j<5000000;j++){}  doesn't simulate sleep. Depending on your compiler optimization setting, it might not generate any code. If it does generate code, it will tie up the CPU for a little while. Impact on other tasks is determined by the OSs scheduling algorithm. In Linux it will usually share CPU equally with other tasks with equal priority.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably having issues with buffering.

Try calling [`fflush()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) after a call to `fprintf()`

```c
fprintf(log, "i=%d, Child Terminal here\n", i); // print to child terminal
fflush(log)
```

Alternatively you could look into line buffering or disabling buffering entirely by using [`setbuf()` / `setvbuf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setbuf)

---

Note also that `for(j=0;j<5000000;j++){}` is *not* a good idea - ever. This is referred to as a "*busy loop*", and will hog processor time - increasing power usage, temperatures, and starving other processes of resources.

This is a bad idea even if you are working on a microcontroller and should be avoided wherever possible.

Additionally, depending on compiler optimisation settings, this may produce no instructions at all, silently making `alternative-3` equivalent to `alternative-1`.